# SQL PIVOT table with MIN() and on Multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Here is the table structure

```
ID          TypeX   TypeXDesc           XDate       TypeCodeY
040001      3669    Unspecified Cat    2005-08-08   1
040001      3669    Unspecified Cat    2006-08-29   2
040001      37515   Tear Film          2005-08-08   1
040001      37999   Disor              2004-07-22   1
```

Transform above table INTO below USING PIVOT

```
ID          TypeX_1 TypeXDesc_1         XDate_1     TypeCodeY_1     TypeX_2 TypeXDesc_2         XDate_2     TypeCodeY_2     TypeX_3 TypeXDesc_3 XDate_3     TypeCodeY_3
040001      3669    Unspecified Cat    2005-08-08   1               37515   Tear Film          2005-08-08   1               37999   Disor       2004-07-22  1
```

Look at the same TypeX code but XDate is different and we need to get Min(XDate) so first row is qualified not the second row.

Comment: Any comments please, minor clue would get me going..

Comment: Quit trying to use the PIVOT operator and use aggregated case expressions.

Comment: I started off with aggregated case expressions but its long time to run the query and some one suggested me to use PIVOT. Also there are 20 columns TypeX_1,2,3...20, it was getting expensive using aggregated case exp

Comment: The PIVOT syntax isn't going to be any better. In fact the aggregated CASE will normally out perform the PIVOT.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using conditional aggregation.  In this case, you can enumerate the rows with within `typex`/`id` groups using `row_number()`.  You can enumerate the groups with  with `typex`/`id` using `dense_rank()`.

Then, use conditional aggregation:

```
select t.id,
       max(case when grpnum = 1 and seqnum = 1 then typex end) as typex_1,
       max(case when grpnum = 1 and seqnum = 1 then TypeXDesc end) as TypeXDesc_1,
       max(case when grpnum = 1 and seqnum = 1 then XDate end) as XDate_1,
       max(case when grpnum = 1 and seqnum = 1 then TypeCodeY end) as TypeCodeY_1,
       max(case when grpnum = 2 and seqnum = 1 then typex end) as typex_12,
       max(case when grpnum = 2 and seqnum = 1 then TypeXDesc end) as TypeXDesc_2,
       max(case when grpnum = 2 and seqnum = 1 then XDate end) as XDate_2,
       max(case when grpnum = 2 and seqnum = 1 then TypeCodeY end) as TypeCodeY_3,
       max(case when grpnum = 3 and seqnum = 1 then typex end) as typex_1,
       max(case when grpnum = 3 and seqnum = 1 then TypeXDesc end) as TypeXDesc_3,
       max(case when grpnum = 3 and seqnum = 1 then XDate end) as XDate_3,
       max(case when grpnum = 3 and seqnum = 1 then TypeCodeY end) as TypeCodeY_3
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id, typex order by xdate as seqnum,
             dense_rank() over (partition by id order by typex) as grpnum
     from t
    ) t
group by id;
```